# Creating an array of Complex numbers in C++

Tags: c++

I want to create an array to store complex numbers such that First input is number of entries n . Each entry is first real part of number followed by complex part .

```
Eg: n=2 
1.0 -1.0
0 3
```

is representation of numbers 1-i , 3i respectively .
This is what I tried .

```
#include<iostream>
#include<complex>

typedef std::complex<double> Complex;

int main() {
int n;
std::cin>>n;
Complex A[n];

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
std::cin>>A[i];

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
std::cout<<A[i]<<" ";

return 0 ;
}
```

I am new to the c++ programming . Please tell me where I went wrong .

Comment: You did not use `std::vector`.

Comment: `Complex A[n];` VLA's (variable length arrays) aren't standard c++. Also `std::complex` doesn't have an overload for `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const std::complex&)`

Comment: @LogicStuff Please elaborate a bit .

Comment: @user0042 I get the variable length array part. I am new to c++  so please put this ". Also std::complex doesn't have an overload for std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const std::complex&) " in a simpler language.

Comment: @AegonTheUnworthy Ooops, I was wrong regarding that: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator_ltltgtgt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, variable length arrays as you introduce with `cin >> n; Complex A[n]` are not part of the C++ standard and might not be supported by your compiler.
Second, if your compiler supports VLAs in general, it will not support to create a VLA of a non-[POD (plain old data)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType) type like `std::Complex`.

To overcome both issues, use a `std::vector` instead of the plain array:

```
std::vector<Complex> A(n);
```